# rewrite.php not exists in elgg installation files

Tags: php, installation, elgg

I am trying to install elgg version 1.12.2 according to documentation http://learn.elgg.org/en/1.x/intro/install.html
I have uploaded elgg on server, created MySql database and created data folder.
After that I open in thew latest chrome my website and process installation starts.
Immediately I have experienced warning:

[image]

I have tried to open "test" link(which points to rewrite.php page) but this page does not exists???
Here is list of all files in my root folder: [http://i.imgur.com/kcQkeei.png](https://i.imgur.com/kcQkeei.png)
I have downloaded latest elgg from https://elgg.org/download.php

Answer (score 1):

Mod Rewrite should be installed and enabled. If you have done this before it seems to be a permission problem.

Try running these commands:

```
    chown apache: path_to_elgg_dir -R
    chmod 644 path_to_elgg_dir -R
```

It might be selinux issue. You can check selinux status using `sestatus -v`.

In order to disable selinux follow this [link](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html).

Answer (score 0):

`rewrite.php` does not exist indeed as it's special path that's supposed to be rewritten by mod_rewrite of equivalent (depending on type of web server you're using). If you get 404, that means you have not configured URL rewriting properly.

The link that you posted yourself contains "Troubleshooting" section. Additionally I'd recommend enabling curl in your PHP configuration to make sure that installer is able to reliably test URL rewriting (your error indicates that it's missing).

You did not mention any issues with following installation documentation? What server are you using? Did you have problems with any steps described in documentation?

Comment: Mod rewrite is enabled: http://i.imgur.com/ViiKGxc.png

  On the same link you can check that apache verison is "Apache/2.4.7"

Comment: Are you running it in subdirectory by any chance? (need to adjust RewriteBase than)

Comment: Not running in subdir. Running in the root ... acess via elgg.mydomain.com